# generate a vector

Tags: c++, math

I have a ray starting from (x0, y0, z0) and ending at a pixel on the screen. Moreover, I have a one screen with A x B pixels.

How can I generate ray from starting point to ending points at (i,j) pixels ?

I know the formula but I could not manage to implement it in c++ . Thanks for help

Comment: What is the formula and where did you fail? What did you try?

Comment: If you just want a raytrace render, use existing raytracing libraries such as povray. If you're doing your own implementation for fun, be more specific about your problem. What's your input? output? explain how the output is computed, and what you are having a problem with?

Answer (score 5):

You have insufficient information.

You need to know:

1. The view point (i.e. what point is the camera looking at)
2. The field of view
3. The "up" and "right" vectors that define the camera's orientation relative to the world coordinates.

Here's some related code from my own ray-tracer:

```
camera::camera(const point3& _eye, const point3& _center) :
    eye(_eye), center(_center)
{
    up.set(0, 1, 0);
    recalc();

    fov(30);
    m_aspect = 4.0 / 3;
}

camera::camera(const point3& _eye, const point3& _center, const vector3& _up) :
    eye(_eye), center(_center), up(_up)
{
    recalc();

    fov(30);
    m_aspect = 4.0 / 3;
}

void camera::recalc()
{
    // renormalise the up vector
    up.normalise();

    // calculate unit view direction vector
    view = vector3(eye, center);
    view.normalise();

    // and the right hand view vector
    right.cross(view, up);
    right.normalise();

    // and re-base the up vector (may not be normalised)
    up.cross(right, view);
}

void camera::fov(double fovy)
{
    m_fovy = math::deg2rad(fovy) / 2.0;
    m_tanf = tan(m_fovy);
}

void camera::aspect(double aspect)
{
    m_aspect = aspect;
}

void camera::aspect(int x, int y)
{
    m_aspect = (double)x / y;
}

ray camera::cast_ray(double x, double y) const
{
    vector3 dir(view);  
    dir.add_scaled(right, m_tanf * m_aspect * x);
    dir.add_scaled(up, m_tanf * y);
    dir.normalise();

    return ray(eye, dir, 0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Now that you've posted some example code, you need to show us a sample image from your raytracer =)

Comment: @paddy https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4713475/raytrace/balls-07.png

Comment: Nice one.  Is that a panel light-source?  Global illumination?

Comment: @paddy It's stochastic (monte carlo) rendering.  Very expensive computationally, but gives fantastic diffuse lighting and diffuse materials, caustics, etc.  See also this one from my earlier Java version - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4713475/raytrace/stochastic-27.png