# How to move a camera using in a ray-tracer?

Tags: c++, camera, transformation, raytracing

I am currently working on ray-tracing techniques and I think I've made a pretty good job; but, I haven't covered camera yet.

Until now, I used a plane fragment for view plane which is located between `(-width/2, height/2, 200)` and `(width/2, -height/2, 200)` [200 is just a fixed number of z, can be changed].

Addition to that, I use the camera mostly on `e(0, 0, 1000)`, and I use a perspective projection.

I send rays from point `e` to pixels, and print it to image's corresponding pixel after calculating the pixel color.[image]

Here is a image I created. Hopefully you can guess where eye and view plane are by looking at the image.

My question starts from here. It's time to move my camera around, but I don't know how to map 2D view plane coordinates to the canonical coordinates. Is there a transformation matrix for that?

The method I think requires to know the 3D coordinates of pixels on view plane. I am not sure it's the right method to use. So, what do you suggest?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892966/6782

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do it.  Here's what I do:

1. Choose a point to represent the camera location (`camera_position`).
2. Choose a vector that indicates the direction the camera is looking (`camera_direction`).  (If you know a point the camera is looking at, you can compute this direction vector by subtracting `camera_position` from that point.)  You probably want to normalize (`camera_direction`), in which case it's also the normal vector of the image plane.
3. Choose another normalized vector that's (approximately) "up" from the camera's point of view (`camera_up`).
4. `camera_right = Cross(camera_direction, camera_up)`
5. `camera_up = Cross(camera_right, camera_direction)` (This corrects for any slop in the choice of "up".)

Visualize the "center" of the image plane at `camera_position + camera_direction`.  The up and right vectors lie in the image plane.

You can choose a rectangular section of the image plane to correspond to your screen.  The ratio of the width or height of this rectangular section to the length of camera_direction determines the field of view.  To zoom in you can increase camera_direction or decrease the width and height.  Do the opposite to zoom out.

So given a pixel position `(i, j)`, you want the `(x, y, z)` of that pixel on the image plane.  From that you can subtract `camera_position` to get a ray vector (which then needs to be normalized).

```
Ray ComputeCameraRay(int i, int j) {
  const float width = 512.0;  // pixels across
  const float height = 512.0;  // pixels high
  double normalized_i = (i / width) - 0.5;
  double normalized_j = (j / height) - 0.5;
  Vector3 image_point = normalized_i * camera_right +
                        normalized_j * camera_up +
                        camera_position + camera_direction;
  Vector3 ray_direction = image_point - camera_position;
  return Ray(camera_position, ray_direction);
}
```

This is meant to be illustrative, so it is not optimized.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me but I think I get the idea. In "Vector3 image_point = i * camera_right + j * camera_up + camera_position + camera_direction;" did you mean normalized_i and normalized_j?

Comment: Actually it worked when I delete camera_position from image_point.

Comment: And last question, when I take close camera_position and camera_lookat, the shapes start to warp due to the viewing angle. Is this natural or did I do something wrong (or at least is there any way to prevent it happening)?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use the normalized i and j (corrected in the answer). Notice that `ray_direction` simply subtracts off `camera_position` immediately after having added it to `image_point`, so you can simply omit it, but I felt that obscured the logic.  I'm not sure what kind of warping you're talking about.  With a very wide angle view, objects do get distorted near the edges of the frame (e.g., spheres will look oblong).

Comment: From a camera's perspective,does it only send just `one` ray to the target pixel?

Comment: @zionpi: The solution I showed just computes one ray through the center of the pixel.  You could certainly extend the idea to pick additional samples by adding or subtracting fractional values to `i` and `j`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy why do we need to correct for the slope and redo the camera_up .. I didn't get that one, any references I could check out?

Comment: @nevermind: Because the original `camera_up` may have been approximate.  Maybe you chose an "up" vector, but then you want to tilt the camera up or down a little bit.  You also need to "tilt" the up vector by the same amount.  The cross product is an easy way to do that (as long as you haven't tilted the camera a full 90 degrees).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy but at the very beginning when we setup the camera do we still need to correct the up vector? here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129253/setting-the-up-vector-in-the-camera-setup-in-a-ray-tracer

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Why you substract 0.5 to (i /width) and (j / height) in normalized_i and normalized_j?

Comment: @RdIP:  If you think of the pixel as a little 1x1 square, you want the ray to go through the middle of it, not the corner.

Comment: Hello, i am sorry but can you explain it further what exactly are "camera_up" and "camera_right"?

Comment: @binaryBigInt:  If you have the camera's position and the direction it's pointing, you don't have quite enough information to know the orientation of the camera.  If you pointed a camera at someone's face, you could turn the camera along the axis its looking, so that the face is sideways or upside down in the image.  So we choose a `camera_up` vector to remove that ambiguity.  From that, we can derive `camera_right`, which, in conjunction with `camera_up`, defines the plane of the film or image sensor in world space.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I have seen other ray tracing camera implementations and they use Aspect Ratio and FOV to compute Ray from camera. Why don't you use it in your formula? Thanks

Comment: @RdIP:  As I said, there are a variety of approaches.  For me, FOV isn't very intuitive, so I prefer to think in terms of focal length and the camera model.  It all boils down to the same transformations.

Comment: @RdIP:  I misspoke in the comment about the -0.5.  Those subtractions are to center the image plane with respect to the camera position and direction vector.

Answer (score 4):

For rasterising renderers, you tend to need a transformation matrix because that's how you map directly from 3D coordinates to screen 2D coordinates.

For ray tracing, it's not necessary because you're typically *starting* from a known pixel coordinate in 2D space.

Given the eye position, a point in 3-space that's in the center of the screen, and vectors for "up" and "right", it's quite easy to calculate the 3D "ray" that goes from the eye position and through the specified pixel.

I've previously posted some sample code from my own ray tracer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892966/6782

Comment: I am lost at field of view calculations. Could you please elaborate on these lines of code:

dir.add_scaled(right, m_tanf * m_aspect * x);
dir.add_scaled(up, m_tanf * y);
dir.normalise();

Comment: `v.add_scaled(d, n)` just does `v += (d * n)` where `d` is a vector, and `n` is the scale factor.  The two lines calculate the point in the view plane that intersects the pixel at `(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are in the range `-1..1`