# Setting the up vector in the camera setup in a ray tracer

Tags: camera, raytracing

I'm reading fundamentals of computer graphics and trying to set up my own ray tracer. the book says "The most common way to construct the camera frame is from the viewpoint, which becomes e, the view direction, which is−w, and the up vector, which is used to construct a basis that has v and w in the plane defined by the view direction and the up direction"

but then I came across [How to move a camera using in a ray-tracer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078243/ray-tracing-camera) which says that we need to correct the up vector for the (slope?) by performing a cross product with the camera direction (w). Why is that?

I'm calling my camera setup with lookAt(0,0,0) and up(0,1,0)

```
// a camera can be constructed using a position, direction and an up vector
Camera::Camera(Vector position, Vector lookAt, Vector up) {
    this->position = position;
    this->lookAt = lookAt;

    // the difference between camera position and where we want
    // to look at is the direction of the camera
    Vector direction = lookAt.diff(position);

    // camera frame
    w = direction.normalize();
    v = up.cross(w).normalize(); // right vector


    // which is the correct up?
    u = up.normalize();
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", u.getX(), u.getY(), u.getZ()); // prints 0 1 0

    u = v.cross(w).normalize(); // the up vector
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", u.getX(), u.getY(), u.getZ()); // prints 0.31 -0.86 -0.41
}
```

Comment: It was _slop_, not _slope_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in the end is a pair of vectors that forms an orthonormal basis for the image plane.  One of those is going to point to the right relative to the orientation of the camera.  The other is going to point up relative to the orientation of the camera.

If the up vector is a general "the sky is that way," and if your camera is not level, then the up vector and the camera-up vector will be slightly different.  The up vector is a hint as to the orientation you want, but it's not exactly the right vector.  In this case, you can cross the right vector with the direction vector, and that'll give you a vector that lies in the image plane and is perpendicular to the right vector.  That's what you want.

If the up vector is a general "the sky is that way," and if your camera *is* level, then the up vector and the camera_up vector will be exactly the same.  The extra cross product would be unnecessary, but there's no harm in it if you want the code to be general enough to handle the first case.

Perhaps some ASCII art can help clarify...

```
^                                        * look-at point
| "up"        "camera up"
|                  \ 
|       image plane \
                     \
                 "camera down"
```

The up vector is straight up.  The look-at point is higher than the camera, so the camera must tilt back a little bit.  In the diagram, we see the edge of the image plane.  The "right" vector is in that plane and pointed out of the diagram.  The direction vector (which your code called `w`) is perpendicular to the image and points directly at the look-at point.

The camera-up vector (`u` in your code) must lie in the image plane, so we can't just use "up".  And it must be perpendicular to the "right" vector.  The easiest way to get that is to cross those two vectors.

Since we generated the "right" vector in terms of the original up vector, that gives us the orientation.

Comment: Using the right hand rule, if you cross the camera direction (should be somewhat similar to the Z axis, going into the picture) and the right vector, you should get a vector approximately going down, not up, right? Also, what is the image plane? Is it the x-y grid through which camera rays go through? or a 3-D sort of box? I guess you're saying you need 2 axes to make this box, which is why we want an up and a right vector, right?

Comment: My answer assumes that the XY plane is the "ground" in world space and that Z is the altitude.  Imagine standing on the floor holding a camera.  It's position has a positive Z component, and it's view vector is nearly parallel to the ground.  (In my diagram, it's pointing slightly upwards.)  The plane of the camera's film (the uv grid) is perpendicular to the view grid.  A common approach is to transform everything until the film plane coincides with the XY plane and the camera points along the Z axis.  That's equivalent, but not what I'm describing here.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the maths behind this whole thing. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932651/what-are-we-trying-to-achieve-by-creating-a-right-and-down-vectors-in-this-ray-t)